# Duplicate images on docker-compose build. How to properly push two services of docker-compose.yml to Docker hub registry?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-registry

I have a `docker-compose.yml` defined as follows with two services (the database and the app):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: .
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=(adminname)
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(adminpassword)
      - CLOUDINARY_URL=(cloudinarykey)
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The reason I have `build: .` in both services is due to how you can't do `docker-compose push` unless you have a `build` in all services. However, this means that both services are referring to the same Dockerfile, which builds the entire app. So after I run `docker-compose build` and look at the images available I see this:

```
$ docker images   
    
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mellon_app              latest              XXXXXXXXXXXX        27 seconds ago      1.14GB
postgres                latest              XXXXXXXXXXXX        27 seconds ago      1.14GB
```

The IMAGE_ID is the exact same for both images, the size is exactly the same for both images. This makes me think I've definitely done some unnecessary duplication as they're both just running the same Dockerfile. I don't want to take up any unnecessary space, how do I do this properly?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM (MY FRIENDS ACCOUNT)/django-npm:latest

RUN mkdir usr/src/mprova

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova

COPY frontend ./frontend
COPY backend ./backend

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova/frontend

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova/backend

ENV DJANGO_PRODUCTION=True
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python3 manage.py collectstatic && \
    python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
    python3 manage.py migrate && \
    gunicorn mellon.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

What is the proper way to push the images to my Docker hub registry without this duplication?

Comment: You're using the `postgres` image for `db`, you don't need to push it. You should remove `build` from the db service

Comment: @IainShelvington so what about my environment variables that I've defined? How could I access them from, let's say, a VPS?

Comment: You pass those environment variables when you run it. The environment variables are not baked into the built image anyway unless your Dockerfile explicitly does so. How are you running the containers?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am currently running the containers locally via ```docker-compose build``` and ```docker-compose up```. Would you recommend adding the environment variables to the Dockerfile instead?

Comment: You already have them in your compose file, they will be passed to the container when you run docker-compose up

Comment: @IainShelvington Please correct me if I'm wrong, but when I push the image to Docker Hub, the ```docker-compose.yml``` file does not go with it?

Comment: No it doesn't and it doesn't need to. However you deploy you app, you need to pass the environment variables as part of the deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way is to do

1. `docker build -f {path-to-dockerfile} -t {desired-docker-image-name}.`
2. `docker tag {desired-docker-image-name}:latest {desired-remote-image-name}:latest` or not `latest` but what you want, like datetime in int format
3. `docker push {desired-remote-image-name}:latest`

and cleanup:
4. `docker rmi {desired-docker-image-name}:latest {desired-remote-image-name}:latest`

Whole purpose of `docker-compose` is to help your local development, so it's easier to start several pods and combine them in local docker-compose network etc...

Comment: So ```docker-compose``` is not something that can be pushed to Docker hub? It's only for local purposes?

Comment: it can be used for all environments, but i never saw it would be used for pushing separate  images. and don't see how it can be used for kubernetes