# Docker image not running, db error: django.db.utils.OperationalError could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, digital-ocean

So I've managed to build my Docker image locally using `docker-compose build` and I've pushed the image to my Docker Hub repository.

Now I'm trying to get it working on DigitalOcean so I can host it. I've pulled the correct version of the image and I am trying to run it with the following command:

`root@my-droplet:~# docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000/tcp mycommand/myapp:1.1` (yes, 1.1)

However I soon run into these two errors:

> ````
> ...
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 185, in get_new_connection
>     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 127, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) 
> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known ```
> ````

> ````
> ... 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 197, in connect
>     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line
> 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 185, in get_new_connection
>     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 127, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) 
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known ```
> ````

This may be due to how I have divided my application (using `docker-compose,yml`) into two services and have only pushed the image of the app since my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210819/duplicate-images-on-docker-compose-build-how-to-properly-push-two-services-of-d?noredirect=1#comment111776613_63210819). Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=(adminname)
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(adminpassword)
      - CLOUDINARY_URL=(cloudinarykey)
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM (MY FRIENDS ACCOUNT)/django-npm:latest

RUN mkdir usr/src/mprova

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova

COPY frontend ./frontend
COPY backend ./backend

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova/frontend

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/mprova/backend

ENV DJANGO_PRODUCTION=True
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python3 manage.py collectstatic && \
    python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
    python3 manage.py migrate && \
    gunicorn mellon.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and here is a snippet of my `settings.py` file:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '[THE PASSWORD]',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
...
```

How can I fix this issue? I've looked around but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

---

From what I saw online, I added the following to my project, but it doesn't work either:

Here is my `base.py` (new file):

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='admin' host='db' password='[THE PASSWORD]'")
```

Additions to `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM (MY FRIENDS ACCOUNT)/django-npm:latest

RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary

COPY base.py base.py

RUN python3 base.py

...
```

Yet the build fails due to this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "base.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='admin' host='db' password='[THE PASSWORD]'")   
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line
> 127, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>         Is the server running on host "db" ([SOME-IP-ADDRESS]) and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python3 base.py' returned a non-zero code: 1 
> me@My-MacBook-Pro-5 mellon %
> ```

I'm unsure as to what to try next but I feel like I am making a simple mistake. Why is the connection being refused at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch a `docker-compose.yml` file, Compose will automatically create a Docker network for you and attach containers to it.  Absent any specific `networks:` declarations in the file, Compose will name the network `default`, and then most things Compose creates are prefixed with the current directory name.  This setup is described in more detail in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

`docker run` doesn't look at the Compose settings at all, so anything you manually do with `docker run` needs to replicate the settings `docker-compose.yml` has or would automatically generate.  To make a `docker run` container connect to a Compose network, you need to do something like:

```sh
docker network ls              # looking for somename_default
docker run \
  --rm -it -p 8000:8000/tcp \
  --net somename_default \     # <-- add this option
  mycommand/myapp:1.1
```

(The specific error message `could not translate host name "postgres" to address` hints at a Docker networking setup issue: the database client container isn't on the same network as the database server and so the hostname resolution fails.  Contrast with a "connection refused" type error, which would suggest one container is finding the other but either the database isn't running yet or the port number is wrong.)

In your `docker build` example, code in a Dockerfile can never connect to a database.  At a mechanical level, there's no way to attach it to a Docker network as we did with `docker run`.  At a conceptual level, building an image produces a reusable artifact; if I `docker push` the image to a registry and `docker run` it on a different host, that won't have the database setup, or similarly if I delete and recreate the database container locally.

Comment: I missed the run part.  Good explanation :)

Comment: When I do ```docker volume ls```, there are no volumes available. Why is this the case?

Comment: I meant `docker network ls`, sorry; I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you. There are three options: bridge, host and none. How do I know which one to select?

Comment: If you've run `docker-compose up -d`, there should be one named `somename_default`, where `somename` is the current directory's name.  Use that one.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to run it with the following command: root@my-droplet:~#
>
> docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000/tcp mycommand/myapp:1.1 (yes, 1.1)

Docker-compose allows to create a composition of several containers.
Running the django container with `docker run` defeats its purpose.

What you want is running :

```
docker-compose build

docker-compose up
```

or in a single command :

```
docker-compose up --build
```

> Why is the connection being refused at the moment?

Maybe because that is not done at the right moment.

I am not a Django specialist but your second try looks ok while your django service misses the Dockerfile attribute in the compose declaration (typing error I assume).

For your first try, that error :

````
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known ```
````

means that django uses "postgres" as host of the database.
But according to your compose, the database could be reached with a host named "db". These don't match.

Regarding your second try that defines database properties, it looks fine and it also matches to what [the official doc states](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) :

> In this section, you set up the database connection for Django.
>
> In your project directory, edit the composeexample/settings.py file.
>
> Replace the DATABASES = ... with the following:
>
> ## settings.py
>
> ```
> DATABASES = {
> 'default': {
>     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
>     'NAME': 'postgres',
>     'USER': 'postgres',
>     'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
>     'HOST': 'db',
>     'PORT': 5432,
> } } These settings are determined by the postgres Docker image specified in docker-compose.yml.
> ```

For your second try, that error :

```
 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "db" ([SOME-IP-ADDRESS]) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

may mean that the Postgres DB listener is not ready yet when Django tries to init the connection with.

That attributes of your compose :   `depends_on:` defines order of container start but doesn't wait for that the application behind the container be "ready".

Here two way to addresse that kind of scenario :

- either add a sleep of some seconds before starting your django service
- or set your django compose conf to restart on failure.

For the first way, configure your django service with a CMD such as (not tried) :

```
   app:
     build: .
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
       - db
     command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 30; python3 manage.py collectstatic && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn mellon.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 "
```

For the second way, try something like that :

```
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not touch my Django Application for a long time, and I run `python manage.py createsuperuser`, then got

````
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known ```
````

Instead, I need to use

```
docker-compose exec [Your Django App] python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Need to run in the container, then it works!